# How to handle object ID's in ember.js?

Tags: mysql, api, rest, symfony, ember.js

I was just experimenting building a tiny app with Emberjs as my frontend framework.

All the app is, is a list which I can add names to with a textbox and button, then remove names from the list by clicking the delete button after each name.

I'm using a very simple Symfony2 application as my data store via a REST API and can currently add names to the list no problem. What I don't understand is how to go about deleting them.

If I add a new name to the list, it won't have the unique ID (my objects have an id and a name) that would be assigned by the DB engine, so when I come to delete it, I can't pass an ID to the DELETE API call.

How do I fix this? Do I need to somehow return the complete object (with ID) when calling the create API call and update the object (how would I do that with Ember?) or is there some other way of doing it?

Edit: Added an image better illustrating my question:

[image]

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: @intuitivepixel - I could, but it would be quite a lot of code to illustrate quite a simple question. It's more of a conceptual/best-practice, question.

Comment: basically you can delete a record from the Store if it's not commited. The Store gives new records an internal id when the record is still uncommited. why do you want do delete a record on the API if it's still not commited? and regarding 'Do I need to somehow return the complete object (with ID) when calling the create API...'  yes, return the entire object with the new id assigned

Comment: @intuitivepixel - Apologies, I'm probably not being clear. If I add a name to the list, then commit it to the store (send a call to my API with the JSON data of my new name) then it's in storage. At that point it'll get it's ID from the DB, but ember won't know anything about it. How do I tell Ember about this new ID?

Comment: when you create a new record you should return the entire object back (with it's id)

Comment: Ah right. I didn't know that was the convention. If I return the full object, will the default Ember-data adapter handle that and assign it to the newly-created object?

Comment: exactly, this is the behaviour

Comment: did it work out for you?

Comment: @intuitivepixel - My code is on another machine, will test it in the morning (though I'm sure it will work) and report back/write a brief answer summarizing the solution for the benefit of others. :-)

Comment: ok, let me know so I can answer and get some rep - just kidding :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, when you create a new record the Store set's an internal id for the record, then when you commit to your backend your API should conveniently return the entire object back (with it's new id) ember will then take care to set the new server-side generated id back to your internally newly created record in the Store.

Answer (score 1):

Your server should be serializing the id back to your ember app. If you're using Ember Data and your models are extensions of `DS.Model`, you don't have to define the `id` property on the model, but you can still use it.